# Рекомендуемые товары в Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, codeigniter

В проекте очень много товаров (единиц), и нужно реализовать в нем возможность в админ панели выбирать n количество товаров, что бы в дальнейшем выводить их в фронтенде.
Вопрос у меня только по части хранения этих данных.
Как я думал это делать:
Создать отдельную таблицу в базе данных куда записывать `id` товара, добавленного админом в рекомендуемые и возможно какие то настройки (все в `json` формате).

Второй же вариант это создать аналогичную таблицу например `widgets` но с дополнительной ячейкой `'name'`, принцип хранения там тот же но только в ячейку name записывается само название хранимой информации в данном случае `features`, что бы при обращении к таблице, выбирать нужные данные по названию.

Удобен мне такой вариант тем что например в этой же таблице я могу хранить еще какую либо похожую информацию, например вывод продуктов в какой то слайдер или тому подобное.

Но так как продуктов в проекте много и поиск по их таблице занимает время (вместе с джоинами), меня интересует еще то, какой является практика хранить в этой дополнительной таблице и саму выводимую данную по продукту, его изображение, имя, цену, и ссылку на него, что бы каждый раз не дергать массивную таблицу продуктов и ее связи.

Фреймворк `codeigniter`

Comment: Вы простите, но, если честно, вообще ничего непонятно

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий, переписал вопрос, возможно так будет понятнее

Comment: В такой постановке я бы рекомендовал Вам поменять теги под вопросом т.к тут вопрос по большей части относится к правильному формированию структуры БД, нормализации таблиц и в последнюю очередь уже к `PHP` и `CodeIgniter`.